# Retrieve data via web service

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

I use the external prestashop web service to retrieve the products
example how can I recover this title the quantity etc ...

```
$productResources = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'products','active' => '0', 'id' => (int)$product_id));
$productWB = $productResources->product;
echo $productWB->name->language; 

result = "{"@attributes":{"id":"2"},"0":"Pantalon de costume - Bleu-Ile de Paques"}"
```

Comment: how to display that "Pantalon de costume - Bleu-Ile de Paques"

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$productResources = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'products','active' => '0', 'id' => (int)$product_id));
$productWB = $productResources->product;
$productb = get_object_vars(json_decode($productWB->name->language));

echo $productb[0];
```